# Need to populate Budget Balance (BudgetRemaining value) in T-SQL code

Tags: t-sql, accounting

I have the following code (see below) which calculates **AmountActual** and **AmountBudget** values for the Period: 07/01/2018 - 03/31/2019

In this code, I also need to populate **AmountBudget** values, but - for the Total Fiscal Year period 7/1/18 - 6/30/19

How do I achieve it in this code?
Thank you for any suggestions...

```
enter 
     DECLARE @FYMonthBOP date = '2018-07-01'
     DECLARE @FYMonthEOP date = '2019-03-31'
     DECLARE @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID int = 8 
     DECLARE @GLProgramGroupsWHID int = -1
     DECLARE @GLProgramsWHID_Groups int = -1

     SELECT        
            trans.GLGroupLevel0Name
          , trans.Ordinal0
          , trans.GLGroupLevel1Name
          , trans.Ordinal1
          , trans.GLGroupLevel2Name
          , trans.Ordinal2
          , trans.GLAccountCode
          , trans.GLAccountName
          , trans.GroupSetName
          , trans.GroupSetNameWHID
          , trans.GroupName
          , trans.GroupNameWHID
          , trans.OrdinalGroupName 
          , trans.Program
          , trans.FQ
          , trans.AmountActual -- these are my main fields I am trying 
          , trans.AmountBudget -- to work with
          , trans.WHIDProgram
          , trans.OrdinalProgram
          , trans.FYMonthNumber
          , trans.FYMonthShortLabel
          , trans.FYQuarterNumber
          , trans.FYNumber
          , trans.FYLabel
          , trans.YearMonthSort
          , trans.BOM
          , trans.EOM
          , trans.DateFrom
          , trans.DateThru

    FROM            
          [Reports].[GLTransMonthlyActualBudget] trans

    WHERE (
          (trans.[EffectiveMonth] BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
      AND (trans.[GroupSetNameWHID] = @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID)
      AND ((trans.[GroupNameWHID] IN (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)) 
            OR (-1 IN (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)))
      AND ((trans.[WHIDProgram] IN (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)) 
            OR (-1 IN (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)))
```

Comment: Self Join will help you to achieve the requirement..

Comment: @Ajay I tried to self join on AmountBudget field, but it doesn't work  I don't know on which field to join ...

Comment: You need to join the same table with different alias name and add the conditions

Comment: @Ajay Yes, and I did it ...   This is the part where I joined it -                                                          
 ......FROM  [Reports].[GLTransMonthlyActualBudget] trans
       INNER JOIN  [Reports].[GLTransMonthlyActualBudget] trans1                    
       ON  trans.AmountActual = trans1.AmountActual                                                
       WHERE trans1.[EffectiveMonth] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2019-06-30'    Works extremely slow, over 2 min   Doesnt look correct

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output....